# Where to see all possible error codes of AwsServiceException?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to handle an `AwsServiceException` based on the error code returned.

Where is the web page that lists out all those possible error codes? I cannot find it in the Java documentation.

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0/software/amazon/awssdk/awscore/exception/AwsServiceException.html

```
    private RuntimeException handleS3Exception(final AwsServiceException exception) {
        if (exception.awsErrorDetails().errorCode().equals("NoSuchKey")) {
            return new ObjectNotFoundException();
        } else {
            return exception;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of all possible error codes:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList